# Is there an algorithm to find a minimum spanning tree that runs in time O(n log k) on a graph that has only k different edges costs?

Tags: algorithm

Such algorithm was left as an exercise to the reader in Skiena's algorithm design book, supposedly it is just a modification of Prim's algorithm ([In his wiki reference](http://www2.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Weighted-graphs-TADM2E) exercise 6-11). Can anyone design such algorithm?

Comment: n = |V| according to my understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prim with a simple priority queue is O(m+n lg n), where m is the number of edges and n the number of vertices. If you bucket entries with the same priority (e.g., use linked lists) you automatically get O(m+n lg k).

AFAIK, the state of the art for this case is O(m), [Fredman and Willard](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000%2805%2980064-9).

Comment: Just to be clear, I believe O(n lg k) in the question is wrong. In fact, I couldn't find such an exercise in Skiena's book

Comment: I added the reference of the exercise to the question. I don't get how if you bucket entries with the same priority you can go from O(m+n logn) to O(m+n logk)

Comment: The priority queue would have at most k elements. In Java, for example, you could use TreeMap<Integer,List<Node>>.

Comment: @cstheoryuser: Question is in Skiena's book: Q.6-11.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the problem should ask for O(m + n log k).    Clearly Omega(m) is a lower-bound, since we cannot even find the lowest-weight edge without checking all of them.

For the record, the convention is that n denotes the number of vertices and m the number of edges.

Enjoy my book :-)

Steven Skiena

Comment: If we use bounded height priority queue (page 374, constant-time insertion and find-min), we could reduce this algorithm to O(m).